# At what point is scrollHeight calculated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a css transition working with an accordian element I'm developing with Angular 7, for when the bottom part expands. As I'm not going to be using the element myself, I am using `overflow-y: visible;` to ensure whatever's placed inside will display properly.

This means that because of using overflow, I'm referencing `max-height` instead of `height` for my transition. I've seen it suggested that to use this transition with overflow I should set the `max-height` to well over what it'll ever need.

Which is fine except that the transition will always use that value and the animation can look pretty stupid depending on what its contents are. To get around this I thought I could wait for the element to be instantiated, have its contents populated, grab it's `scrollHeight` and then set that as the `max-height`.

Which I can do (and it does work) with a `setTimeout` used within `ngAfterViewInit()` but the `scrollHeight` isn't calculated and defined until about 70ms later (according to some timeout-testing), yet the `textContent` is there instantly.

It just got me thinking, is there a certain point when `scrollHeight` is calculated and is there any way to hook onto that event or anything? I don't want to rely on a weird arbitrary time value with `setTimeout()`.

Just a concept question, don't think you need any code or anything? Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes applied to the DOM elements are not applied immediately, all the changes made to the DOM in a single execution cycle are collected and applied in one repaint.

So you need to wait for the repaint to complete before trying to read the updated dimensions of the element.

`requestAnimationFrame` is a method that is executed before every repaint, if you write your code like this

```
element.style.display = 'block';
requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log(element.scrollHeight));
```

The callback will be executed before the next repaint and you should get the updated scrollHeight.